# How to save audio file in core data and send to server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, avaudiorecorder

I'm creating record audio and save that file in device after that I want to send to server. For this i'm writing code like this

```
_playAudioOutlet.enabled = NO;
_stopRecording.enabled = NO;

NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSLog(@"%@",soundFilePath);
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
}
// to start recording...

- (IBAction)startRecording:(UIButton *)sender {

if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
{
    _playAudioOutlet.enabled = NO;
    _stopRecording.enabled = YES;
    [_audioRecorder record];
}

}

// To stop recording
- (IBAction)stopRecording:(UIButton *)sender {

_stopRecording.enabled = NO;
_playAudioOutlet.enabled = YES;
_startRecording.enabled = YES;

if (_audioRecorder.recording)
{
    [_audioRecorder stop];
} else if (_audioPlayer.playing) {
    [_audioPlayer stop];
}

}

// TO play audio

- (IBAction)playAudio:(UIButton *)sender {

if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
{
    _stopRecording.enabled = YES;
    _startRecording.enabled = NO;

    NSError *error;

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url
                    error:&error];

    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    else
        [_audioPlayer play];
}
}
```

I'm writing code like this...it's working fine. But now i want to store that data in core data and after saving data i want to send. For this I created core data and with Entity name:Save, attribute name:save type binary data. But i am getting error. 
Can any one give solution for this...

```
- (IBAction)stopRecording:(UIButton *)sender {

// Get conntext
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

// Save data
NSManagedObject *newSong;
newSong = [NSEntityDescription
           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Save"
           inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error;

NSURL *urlOfRecording = _audioRecorder.url;
NSString *url = [urlOfRecording absoluteString];
NSLog(@"in saveRecording, the url is: %@",url);
[newSong setValue:url forKey:@"save"];
[context save:&error];
//    status.text = @"Song Saved!";

_stopRecording.enabled = NO;
_playAudioOutlet.enabled = YES;
_startRecording.enabled = YES;

if (_audioRecorder.recording)
{
    [_audioRecorder stop];
} else if (_audioPlayer.playing) {
    [_audioPlayer stop];
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coredata has a 'allow external storage' option when saving binary data with coredata which will automatically store files larger than 1mb to the disk. You are already saving your data in application document dictionary. So just pull data from document directory and send it to your server using HTTP/UDP (what ever the protocol).
Pull your data from directory:

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
NSData dataToBeSentInServer = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: soundFilePath];
```

Comment: Ok, actually I want to copy that file and re save  with another name. Now i want to send to server. How to re save file...

Comment: This is not true. An audio file CAN be saved to Core Data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280989/renaming-an-existing-file-with-obj-c

Comment: what is name in previous comment

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126070/1746086) link you don't have to store any audio file in your core data. You can store in your local directory and then upload to server with background threads.